# Symfony existing public service throws error message "You have requested a non-existing service"

Tags: symfony, service

I am starting to work with services in Symfony and therefore created the example service from the symfony documentation:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
  private $logger;
  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger){

  }
    public function getMessage()
    {
        $this->logger->info('Success!');
    }
}
```

I call that service in my controller (I also have the use Statement: 
: `use AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator;`

```
  $messageGenerator = $this->get(MessageGenerator::class);
  $message = $messageGenerator->getMessage();
  $this->addFlash('success', $message);
```

My service is defined in the services.yml file:

```
    app.message_generator:
    class: AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator
    public: true
```

so in my eyes I did everything exactly as described in the documentation and when calling:

```
    php app/console debug:container app.message_generator
```

in my commandline I get my service:

```
  Option             Value                               
 ------------------ ------------------------------------ 
  Service ID         app.message_generator               
  Class              AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator  
  Tags               -                                   
  Scope              container                           
  Public             yes                                 
  Synthetic          no                                  
  Lazy               no                                  
  Synchronized       no                                  
  Abstract           no                                  
  Autowired          no                                  
  Autowiring Types   -
```

Now when I execute the controller function where I call my service I still get the error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "appbundle\service\messagegenerator".
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony is a bit confusing at naming: you retrieve the service by requesting it by its defined name: `app.message_generator`.

```
 $messageGenerator = $this->get('app.message_generator');
```

Comment: Or, as an alternative, replace app.message_generator with the class name in the service definition file.  This in turn allows you to eliminate the class: line and is also more in line with the latest container recommended practices.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony has recently suggested switching from a give-name (`app.message_generator`) that you are defining the service as, to the class name (`AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator`). They are both just 'a name' to call the service.

You are trying to use both, when only the given name is defined.

In the long term, it's suggested to use the `::class` based name, and quite possibly allow the framework to find the classes itself, and configure them itself too. This means that, by default, all services are private, and are handled by the framework & it's service container.

In the meantime, while you are learning, you can either:

```
$messageGenerator = $this->get('app.message_generator');
```

or define explicitly define the service, and make it public, so it can be fetched with `->get(...)` from the container.

```
# services.yml
AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator:
    class: AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator
    public: true

# php controller
$messageGenerator = $this->get(MessageGenerator::class);
```

or just injected automatically into the controller, when that is requested

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, MessageGenerator $msgGen)
{
    $this->messageGenerator = $msgGen;
}

public function getMessage()
{
    $result = $this->messageGenerator->do_things(....);
    $this->logger->info('Success!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it would have solved my problem, too, but sics was faster, so I accepted his answer. :)